# I don't know how to fix module 'adoptme.views' has no attribute 'addfriends'

Tags: python

Nevermind, I don't need help anymore. I got it after I looked over some notes.

Comment: I can't find adoptme by googling - is your own project? If so, I'd guess you don't have a function addfriends in adoptme.views - it either does not exist at all or has a different name (add_friends could be a good candidate)

Comment: please add your `view` code

Answer (score 0):

correct your url configuration

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^addfriends/$', views.addfriends, name='friends'),
url('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but I think it is views.index and not addfriends, also how you set the url template.

```
url(r'^addfriends/$', views.index, name='friends'),
```

that should work